# Create input output procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `Transaction` table with the following columns:

```
PoojaDetailsID,
ReceiptNo - computed varchar(25) contains a combination of both characters and numbers,
ReceiptDate,
FirstName,
LastName,
TelNo and many other columns...
```

I would like to create a stored procedure to insert data in the transaction table and capture the `ReceiptNo` for the inserted record as an `Output` parameter. I am using an ASP.net application to store the data.

Please advise.

Comment: How will you determine the value of ReceiptNo ?? will the users pass the value for ReceiptNo  Variable ?

Comment: No, the user will pass the other fields. Upon inserting the data the Receipt No is generated automatically. I would like to capture that Receipt No for which I insert data using Stored Procedure. ReceiptNo is generated based on PoojaDetailsID. PoojaDetailsID is Primary Key.

Comment: well the in my answer you can set the value of ReceiptNo using whatever logic you use to Create and then return it by passing a parameter of varchar(25) type and using key word OUTPUT when passing parameter, but I am sure the following code will give you a good place to start, tweak the code a bit further to suite your needs .

Comment: Thanks but how to get the ReceiptNo for the current inserted record? As the value is generated using computed column which is defined in the table definition...

Comment: Is `PoojaDetailsID` an IDENTITY column?

Comment: In any event, do you know how to write a stored procedure at all? Do you know how to insert rows? Do you know how to declare an OUTPUT parameter? Please show (in your question) what you *can* do and what particularly poses the difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

there are many things do say about it.. Hope this example will suffice your needs.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DoTheJob
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Param1 varchar(10),
    @param2 varchar(20),
    @result  varchar(30) output
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    set @result='actually put the requred code di fill the result'

    insert into YourTable select from YourData 

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE Procedure usp_SomeName
    @PoojaDetailsID     INT         = NULL,
    @ReceiptNo          varchar(25) = NULL OUTPUT,
    @ReceiptDate        Datetime    = NULL,
    @FirstName          VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @LastName           VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @TelNo              VARCHAR(50) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        IF @ReceiptNo IS NULL
             RAISERROR('Validation Failed: ReceiptNo name cannot be null', 16,1)

        IF EXISTS (SELECT ReceiptNo FROM dbo.TableName
                   WHERE ReceiptNo = @ReceiptNo)
              RAISERROR('Validation Failed: ReceiptNo Name already Exists',16,1)

        BEGIN TRANSACTION
          INSERT INTO TableName(Column1, Column2, Column3,....)
          VALUES (@Variable1, @Variable2, @Variable3,.... )

          COMMIT TRANSACTION

        SET @ReceiptNo =        ---<----- How ever you will determine the value of @ReceiptNo 
                                --<-----  if your user will pass the value then just set the variable
                                --<----   Then Just Using the The Key word "OUTPUT" will do the trick 
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH 
       IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
         ROLLBACK TRAN

       SELECT @ReturnCode = ERROR_NUMBER(), @ReturnMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()

      SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ERRORNUMBER, 
             ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ReturnMessage,
             ERROR_LINE()   AS ErrorLine,
             ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
             ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
    END CATCH

   SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END
GO
```

When calling the stored procedure, declare a variable of type `@RtnReceiptNo varchar(25)` and pass it to the stored procedure with using the key word `OUTPUT`.

Something like this ...

```
DECLARE @RtnReceiptNo varchar(25) = '12BCkj12KK'

EXECUTE  usp_SomeName
     @PoojaDetailsID = 1,
     @ReceiptNo      = @RtnReceiptNo OUTPUT,
     @ReceiptDate    = 'SomeDate',
     @FirstName      = 'FistName',
     @LastName       = 'LastName',
     @TelNo          = '1465161516'

SELECT @RtnReceiptNo
```

**Edit**

Since your `@ReceiptNo` is coming from calculated columns or from where ever you will have to do some extra steps in your code to capture that .

Declare a `Table Variable` with One column with Datatype of  `@ReceiptNo` Then In your Insert Statement use the `OUTPUT` Clause to get the inserted values of  @ReceiptNo  and INSERT INTO your table variable and then `SELECT` it from there to assign that value to your OUTPUT variable of the stored procedure.

The rest of the stored procedure definition remains same just change the INSERT Statement as follows

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (Value VARCHAR(25))   --<--- Table variable to insert the @ReceiptNo values

INSERT INTO Table_Name (Column1, Column2, Column3, ....)
OUTPUT   inserted.ReceiptNo INTO @tbl              ---<---- Using OUTPUT and inserted Table retrieve 
VALUES (Value1, 'Value2',....)                         --the newly inserted ReceiptNo values and  
                                                       ---insert into your Table Variable 

SELECT @ReceiptNo = Value FROM @tbl                 --<--- Retrieve the value from table variable and
                                                      -- store it into the variable you will OUTPUT
                                                      -- from you stored procedure
```

Comment: Thanks but how to get the ReceiptNo for the current inserted record? As the value is generated using computed column which is defined in the table definition...

Comment: @Rajiv Have a look now pal, I have updated my answer use this INSERT statement I have added now in the answer to get the newly inserted  value of ReceiptNo, Not a very straight forward way but will get the JOB DONE :)